# Refresh web api

Tags: c#, .net

Hello I initialize the api/page using a simple web api controller, my question is how to reinitialize the xml values every few seconds without refreshing the whole page. The scope of this is to detect the database changes (if any) and show them in real time on the page.

My api is similar to this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

the api is initialized with data from the db, but i want to continously recall the function so the values would change if the the db values change.

Comment: I think you are talking about a lookup database which the API would refer on regular intervals

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: i think you are doing it wrong - but it may be worth looking into a technology like angular to do it right

Comment: @Sergiu what you need is a simple function which can call the database at some interval and reinitialize the values in your API with the values taken from database.

Comment: What you are looking for is SignalR I think.

Comment: @Souvik that is what I don't know how to do: reinitialize the values in the api.

Comment: basic webapi example code usually queries the db live, so each time you run the code it would query the db. the simplest version of this i can imagine is a META tag on the html page that simply refreshes the page every few seconds..

Comment: @FilipCordas Not necessarily. OP just want's to reinitialize the new values from database. It can be done using a simple Timer function instead of adding SignalR to the project.

Comment: can you give me a simple example on how to use the timer within the controller class to reinitialize?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh you are right. But if he want's "real time app"  This will not do.

Comment: @Sergiu I don't think you understand what is going on here what do you mean reinitialize? You want to update the list with new values every N seconds.

Comment: @FilipCordas SignalR would require a web browser. We may not need a web browser for the API in some cases. Near real time hits can be achieved with the timer interval set to seconds, but I don't think it is really needed to call the database so frequently. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, even every few minutes would be ok. The values from the db need to be shown ever few seconds.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh As I said I think you need much more knowledge on basic of REST services before starting to build Real Time web apps.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh To elaborate REST by design is stateless and uses client server paradigm not PtoP.

Comment: Don't do this, if you want real time data REST is a very bad option, use a permanent connection with WebSockets to the server and then push the changes from the server to the clients when those happen. Unless your database has a very high rate of changes per second it will be more effective, will use a lot less bandwidth and will be more responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Per your example, something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
setInterval(
  // Send an AJAX request
  $.getJSON(uri)
      .done(function (data) {
        //clear products list
        $('#products').html('');
        // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
          // Add a list item for the product.
          $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#products'));
        });
      });
      , 3000);
});
```

This will call your API endpoint every three seconds, clear the `products` element and reload the list. This method is called polling and will be called whether your data has changed or not. You could also implement this via SignalR, which would be closer to real-time and would be event driven refreshing, but that might be more complicated than what you are trying to do.

Comment: yes,but this does not work because the api endpoint does not change. I am asking how to change the api endpoint.

Comment: Can you post your controller code? I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by "the API endpoint does not change". The API endpoint should never change - the data that the API endpoint retrieves should change. Do you mean you want to send a request to a different API endpoint (action) altogether?

Comment: Unlike the example my Product array is initialized using a function, I want every few seconds to recall this function and reintialize the values in the controller.

Comment: Right - that's exactly what my code does with `setInterval` and the 3000 millisecond parameter. If the code in your controller makes a database call, my code posted above will requery your database every 3 seconds and populate your Product array, and update your page to display the new information. Again, I think there is a miscommunication occurring here. Can you please post your controller code? I think that would clear things up.

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do here, but I'm still a bit confused. Are you trying to show the last machine entered into your database? Right now, you only show 1 item per request. I think you might want to reevaluate your API design. Right now it looks like your action takes an integer parameter to retrieve a machine with a specific ID. How will the web browser know which ID to request? Why are you getting an array of machines only to return one machine in JSON? Also, it's recommended that you edit your original question with the code as opposed to adding it as an answer on SO.

Answer (score 0):

As per your request, this is a simple timer function

```
using System.Timers:

Timer timer; = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 10000; // 10 seconds, change this as required
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Timer_Elapsed);
timer.Enabled = true;
timer.Start();
void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    //Call your database function and initialize as you want here
    timer.Start();
}
```

Or you can refer this (recommended)-

[Scheduling Web Api method to run on set intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383388/scheduling-web-api-method-to-run-on-set-intervals)

Comment: Yes. Also please check the second approach which is very similar to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting something from  particular table and tables values always change right . Ones you are created web api and if you want to refresh . You need to schedule the api(url). Which means that just need to trigger it.

If you are using windows you can schedule your api(url).

step1: Go to control panel  and select administrative Tools.

Step2: After that select tack scheduler .

step3: Right side Actions you can see "Create Task"

step4:it will redirect to new window . In general just add name .

```
  Step4.1:- click on  Trigger . There you can schedule it properly(Time and date or daily)
  Step4.2:-After that click on Action . Create click new .
         There youn can see Program\script: add your path like this: 
       "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

           one more option is there "Add Arguments(optional)": "Here you can 
          add your api link or url"
```

click ok . its completed . have a wonderful day. Thank you .

Answer (score -1):

```
 public class MachineController : ApiController
{

    Machine[] machines = Gateway.test2(10);




    public IEnumerable<Machine> GetAllMachines()
    {

        return machines;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult GetMachine(int id)
    {
        var machine = machines.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.id == id);
        if (machine == null)
        {
            return NotFound();

        }
        else
            return Ok(machine);
    }




}
```

}

```
 public static Machine[] test2(int i)
    {
        Machine[] result = new Machine[i+1];

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {

            result[j] = testDatabaseCon(j + 1);
            result[j].id = j + 1;
        }

        result[i] = new Machine();
        result[i].name = "test";
        result[i].description = "test";


        result[i].EnteredCount++;

        return result;

    }
```

Comment: This is not an answer edit the question if you think it's needed.